# How to close all tabs but active in Qt4(QTabWidget)

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt4

How to close all tabs but active in `QTabWidget`, when i know a active tab index, and counts of tabs?
The function of closing all tabs is `tabwidget->clear();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
// remove all tabs after current
for (int i = tabWidget.count() - 1; i > tabWidget.currentIndex(); --i) {
   tabWidget.removeTab(i);
}

// current tab is now the last, therefore remove all but the last
for (int i = tabWidget.count(); i > 1; --i) {
   tabWidget.removeTab(0);
}
```

Comment: This may break down because every time you remove a tab with a rank below `currentIndex`, this index as well as `count` change. Your best bet is to start from the back and erase all tabs above `currentIndex`. Then you go to the beginning and erase all tabs but the last.

Comment: Before your code mauve have a the same error as me. Your fixed code have a small bug:     for (int i = ui->tabWidget->count() - 1; i > ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(); --i) {
       ui->tabWidget->removeTab(i);
    }

    // current tab is now the last, therefore remove all but the last
    for (int i = ui->tabWidget->count()/* - 1*/; i > 1; --i) {
       ui->tabWidget->removeTab(0);
    }
This code work correctly. But thank you very much mauve and rpsml :)

Answer (score 1):

Working solution, the class this comes from inherits QTabWidget:

```
void closeOtherTabsRequested(int index)
{
    auto selectedWidget = widget(index);
    auto tabCount = mTabBar->count();
    for(auto i = tabCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        auto currentWidget = widget(i);
        if(currentWidget != selectedWidget) {
            tabCloseRequested(i);
        }
    }
}
```